# Positioning String with drawAtPoint ?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uiimage

I'm trying to draw a string with **drawAtPoint**, not with **CGContextShowTextAtPoint**.

```
- (UIImage *)drawonimage:(UIImage *)img {
// myString is a string to draw
// fontName is a string (font name)
// fontSize is the font size (CGfloat)

CGFloat w = img.size.width;
CGFloat h = img.size.height;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size,NO,1.0f);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace0 = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context0 = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,w,h,8,4 * w,colorSpace0,kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
CGContextDrawImage(context0,CGRectMake(0,0,w,h),img.CGImage);
CGPoint p0 = CGPointMake(0,0);
[img drawAtPoint:p0];
CGPoint p1 = CGPointMake(0,0);
UIColor *aColor;
aColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:100/255.0 green:120.0/255.0 blue:140.0/255.0 alpha:90/100.0];
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),aColor.CGColor);
[myString drawAtPoint:p1 withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize]];
UIImage *Img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return Img;
}
```

The problem that I have is where the string actually appears.  For instance, let me suppose that the string that I want to draw is "Hello world!"  The very top-left corner of the string is not positioned at 0,0.  (See picture)  The appearance depends on the font, font size and other factors, I suppose.  So I wonder if there's a way of measuring the string height (not width)?  **Or what can I do so that the very top-left corner of the string (at the arrow) will be positioned at 0,0?**

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that is not trivial... `sizeWithFont` would always return the largest possible value for the height tough it returns the correct value for the width...

As pointed here ([How do I calculate the exact height of text using UIKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751219/how-do-i-calculate-the-exact-height-of-text-using-uikit)), you'll need to have a look to the CoreText Framework (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533).

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't seen that 'How do I calculate...' topic.